# Calculate bytes sent and received per IP in specific duration

Tags: python, networking, monitoring

I have a cluster of 4 machines. I need to create a network monitor that runs in the background and monitors the network traffic for the duration of training. Specifically, I need to calculate how much bytes are sent and received among those machines with each other. For example, consider 4 machines `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` and `TX` as bytes sent, `RX` as bytes received, I need something like this by the end of training:

```
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   |      A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   |  TX  |  RX  |  TX  |  RX  |  TX  |  RX  |  TX  |  RX  |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A |  --  |  --  | 1254 | 1523 | 4651 | 3509 | 3551 | 4530 |
| B | 8564 | 8524 |  --  |  --  | 2541 | 6501 | 8460 | 4563 |
| C | 5654 | 6542 | 9654 | 4530 |  --  |  --  | 4534 | 4853 |
| D | 2548 | 2458 | 1235 | 1250 | 7581 | 2485 |  --  |  --  |
+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I created a thread where I monitor the traffic at 200ms interval:

```
# Before training start
total_bytes_sent = 0
total_bytes_recv = 0

io = psutil.net_io_counters()
bytes_sent, bytes_recv = io.bytes_sent, io.bytes_recv

# After training start, during each 200ms interval
io = psutil.net_io_counters()
total_bytes_sent += io.bytes_sent - bytes_sent
total_bytes_recv += io.bytes_recv - bytes_recv
```

This approach has two problems:

1. It provides the overall bytes sent and received to and from anywhere, even the ssh.
2. I cannot monitor the specific IPs with this approach.

The bytes sent and received using this approach are never zero even when there is no communication among the machines. I need to get the total number of bytes send and received as well as the total communication time only among the 4 machines in the cluster for the duration of training.

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21285210/22487733) but it gives me this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

at line:

```
sniff(iface=interface, prn=traffic_monitor_callback, store=False, timeout=sample_interval)
```

I also tried `pyshark` but I couldn't make it work for what I want to achieve.

Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: root/admin privileges are required to capture packets from the network stack. Could that explain the PermissionError ?

Comment: So, it cannot be done without `root` privileges? it's not possible to get `root` privileges in my scenario.

Comment: Linux capabilities provide a fine grained control over privileges. You need the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability (maybe also `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, not sure). Ask your admin, if that is possible. Without admin's permission nobody can analyze packets. After all it is eavesdropping.